# Deserialize an XML string to an object C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have this class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Cat")]
public class Cat
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the cat name
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("CatName")]
    public string CatName{ get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the cat origin
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("CatOrigin")]
    public string CatOrigin{ get; }
}
```

I'm trying to Deserialize this string to my object 'Cat'

```
string myString= "<Cat CatName= \"A\" CatOrigin=\"B\" />";
```

I'm using this method to deserialize :

```
 public Cat DeserializeCat(string def)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cat));
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(def);
        object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Cat XmlData = (Cat)obj;
        reader.Close();
        return XmlData;
    }
```

But i'm always getting an object with a null values for each parameters.
Do you have any idea why i'm not getting the values from my string to my object please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your properties in `Cat` class are read only as it contains only `get`.

To store data into respective property you need to use `set`.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Cat")]
public class Cat
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the cat name
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("CatName")]
    public string CatName{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the cat origin
    /// </summary>
    [XmlAttribute("CatOrigin")]
    public string CatOrigin{ get; set; }
}
```

POC:

[image]

Reference: [set(C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/set)